# Mixing AngularJS with Phalcon Framework

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phalcon

I'm building a multi-module webapp in Phalcon, basically structured as follows:

```
my-project/
├── apps
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   └── IndexController.php
│   │   ├── Module.php
│   │   └── views
│   │       └── index
│   │           └── index.phtml
│   └── frontend
│       ├── controllers
│       │   └── IndexController.php
│       ├── Module.php
│       └── views
│           └── index
│               └── index.phtml
├── common
│   └── config
│       └── config.ini
└── public
    └── index.php
```

You may notice that there is a module for the Admin area and another one for the Front-end side. Now I would like to build the Admin area with AngularJS, with the traditional AngularJS app structure made of several files, folders and subfolders. So I have a two-fold question:

1. Where is the most useful and sensible place to put the AngularJS project folder?
2. How can I redirect from `IndexController.php` of the Admin area to the actual `index.html` of the AngularJS app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does border on personal opinion, but here's how I see it:

1. Your angularjs javascript code will need to be in the public folder (or symlinked) so it gets served, no way around that.
2. To redirect you can use `$this->response->redirect("http://example.com/my/ng/app", true);` wherever you decide to put it

However I would say that redirecting is unnecessary. Why not put your angularjs template in the index.phtml of the view? All of your angular templates can be just phalcon views.

On a personal note, I started off doing a hybrid admin system part phalcon, part angularjs... and as I have gone on there is less and less phalcon in there; angularjs just makes a lot of it seem unnecessary. Now most of my pages start off getting their initial data from the controller to save an ajax request, and even having the templates served all in one go

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myInitialData = <?=json_encode( $dataFromController )?>;
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
    html for template ajax uses goes here
</script>

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <!-- controller can access data with $window.myInitialData -->
    html here
</div>
```

And then communicate with the phalcon controllers via json

Answer (score 0):

phalcon.angular.bootstrap - Boilerplate for a non single page implementation of Angular, Phalcon, and Bootstrap
phalanx - A starter app with Phalcon PHP Framework and Angular

from https://packagist.org/packages/phalcon/awesome-phalcon